# XCode4 Override Repository Offline

Tags: xcode, git, xcode4

I decided to try out the integrated version control feature in XCode 4 (using git). I have an ssh config file that looks similar to this:

`Host server

     Hostname server.example.com

     Port 1234`

When I add the repository to XCode I give it the url `git@server:repo.git`. It is able to clone the repo just fine. Now comes the problem. When I want to push commits to the remote repository, XCode tells me "Repository is offline" (with the little red light). It disables the "Push" button so it won't even try. However, I can pop open a terminal and push it from there just fine (`git push`).

Is there any way to tell XCode to back off and ignore that "error"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you can. XCode appears to be checking to see if it can resolve the name of the remote machine. A workaround is to add `server` to your hosts file so that it resolves the address. The ip address doesn't even have to be correct since it is discarded anyway when the ssh config file is read.